# gradle project dependency in idea

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle

I have configuration in one subproject(A) that produce test artifact:

```
configurations {
    testArtifacts.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
task testJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier "test"
    from sourceSets.test.output
}
artifacts {
    testArtifacts testJar
}
```

and in another subproject(B) I want to use that artifact:

```
compile project (path: ":a-sub-project", configuration: 'testArtifacts')
```

this works perfectly fine from gradle, but when I import project to idea(through built-in support), idea can't see classes from that artifact. It can see classes from main artifact of (A), but not from test one.

Any ideas?

PS. Idea 14.1.4, gradle 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

For us  this works fine:

```
testCompile project(':module').sourceSets.test.output
```

So you don't need the test-jar task actually